# Duplicate interface definition for class (Xcode, ObjC)

Tags: ios

i'm trying to add the SDK of google admob in my game but when i try to build the project after adding the admob sdk, i keep getting the error "Duplicate interface definition for class GADInterstitial"
However, when I do the same in a fresh project, I don't run into any issues at all. I have checked all the imports and project settings, they are all the same.
What should I look for, to resolve such an issue ?

Comment: It might possible that you are integrating the Framework and Headers separately, it should be single import.

Answer (score 0):

You have two interfaces with the same name. Use Xcode's find in project menu option to find instances of "GADInterstitial".

Hope it will be help you.

Answer (score 0):

The Objective-C `#import` pre-processor statement specifically ignores duplicate header files, unlike the C/C++ `#include` pre-processor statement (where it's necessary to use guard macros or `#pragma once`).

So I think you are using `#include "GADInterstitial.h"`, instead of `#import "GADInterstitial.h"`, somewhere in your source tree.